# In modern writing is there a a significant difference between satire and parody?

Tags: style, genre

Are there significant differences between satire and parody?  Can you provide examples of the difference?  Do you know of a book which is considered satire; one which is considered parody?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Parody** is a mockery of a specific existing thing. Weird Al Yankovic writes parodies — "Beat It" as "Eat It," for example. *Saturday Night Live* parodies political figures by mimicking their qualities to extremes.

**Satire** mocks general things and overall qualities and stereotypes, by being an exaggerated copy or twisting some element ironically. In *South Park: Bigger, Longer, and Uncut,* Satan's big song "Up There" was a satire of Disney "hero/ine has a dream" songs.

*Blazing Saddles* is a satire of Westerns; *Men in Tights* is a parody of the Robin Hood myth.

**ETA** examples in books: in addition to @what's good examples, you have Sol Weinstein's [Israel Bond series](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_10?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=sol%20weinstein&sprefix=sol+weinst%2Caps%2C379), which are parodies of James Bond. There's the *Barry Trotter* unauthorized parodies of the Harry Potter series. You could argue that *Pride and Prejudice and Zombies* is a parody. *The Wind Done Gone* is both parody and satire. Ian Doescher has *brilliantly* rewritten the *Star Wars* trilogy as Shakespearean plays.

*Catch-22* is a satire of the military, government, and war. Jonathan Swift's "A Modest Proposal" is a satirical suggestion for dealing with overpopulation, and *Gulliver's Travels* satirizes various faults of character of different groups of people. Hugh Laurie's *The Gun Seller* starts as a satire of noir pulp but changes to an actual noir about halfway through. Douglas Adams's *Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* satirizes bureaucracy (among many other subjects).

If you google "satire novels" and "parody novels" you will come up with plenty of examples.

Comment: Great explanation. Do you have any examples of books, especially novels?  thanks

Answer (score 1):

A **parody** makes fun of an artistic work by applying the characteristic style or theme to unlikely subjects. Example: [Bored of the Rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bored_of_the_Rings).

**Satire** mocks real people, their behavior, and their opinions. One of the most famous satires is probably George Orwell's *[Animal Farm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Farm)*, a satire of Stalinism.

Comment: Good examples. Thx